# androidstudio gradle sync not correctly works

Tags: android, gradle, gson

I have not included gson-2.3.1.jar to my dependencies on gradle.build file. But it gives me below error when going to sync it.

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
> > Could not download gson.jar (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1)
> >     Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.jar'.
> >     Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.jar'.
> >     Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused

Why it gives me such error and why it looks for gson. Yes before i have added it. but then excluded it from dependencies list.
Here is my gradle files:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "az.epul.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
}
```

What i noticed, if i am going to add retrofit.jar to lib and then adding it to dependencies on build.gradle file such way =>   **compile files('libs/retrofit-1.9.0.jar')** it works, but direct adding with  **compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'** not works

Comment: you said you didn't included gson in your in your gradle file but is included in your dependencies..
compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')

Comment: In your project delete the lib Which is in File->project structure ->app-> dependencies , clean the project and run

Comment: @SatishPathuri no success. gives same error

Comment: take back of the code and delete existing project and re-import and sync Again

Comment: try clean and build now

Comment: @MustanserIqbal when i clean project it gives error that it could not download gson.jar

Comment: m not sure but may this error is due to retrofit i think its using gson an thats why its causing error... download gson.jar file from here https://github.com/google/gson and put in your libs folder and then add this file as a dependence and then try to syc the project

Comment: no it is not right. http://blog.robinchutaux.com/blog/a-smart-way-to-use-retrofit/   on this link says that i must include gson

Comment: ok just go to file->project structure->app->dependencies->library dependence-> add GSON library and i hope it will resolve your error...

Comment: it is an old tutorial `25 September 2014.` from my personal experience I'm telling you that you don't need to include dependency of `Gson` for using `retrofit`. It will auto include `Gson` @AEMLoviji

Comment: @Kaushik i agree with you. but i really excluded gson from everywhere. what about this? Why it is still looking for it? I can not understand it.

Comment: As I told you retrofit auto include `Gson` for using retrofit gson is needed if you delete that from external library folder it will try to find it that's why you are facing that problem maybe.

Comment: @Kaushik i do not want to use it. how make so that, it would not to try to find it?

Comment: @Kaushik i am facing this problem  not only with gson but with okhttp too.
here is my okhttp include com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0

Comment: for using retrofit you have to use those libraries **without those libraries you can't use Retrofit** `Gson` , `OkHttp` , `Okio`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91070/discussion-between-aemloviji-and-kaushik).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add gson.jar in your libs folder ,just add the below in your dependencies to use gson

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
```

Remove jar file from libs and compile this again

Comment: firstly i tried it with this way as you said, but no success. Maybe you can test on your machine. and sent me correct build.gradle files?

Comment: I am using it in my project the same I copied above , I am not using.jar file for gson so if you are using then please remove that .jar file

Comment: no i updated question. it was dependencies when i tried gson include with .jar way. Both of two ways is not working. But my question was that: i have not included it on my project but it looks for it

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this block before your dependencies section in build.gradle

```
repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
```

Theoretically this should not be required. But I have faced similar problems without specifying repository.

Answer (score 0):

get data from jcenter() need some filtering Tunnel ! in Iran for example.
use mavenCentral for get retrofit or somethings like this...

add this line in graddle

```
buildscript {
repositories {

   mavenCentral()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
}
```