# retrofit cannot access HttpUrl

Tags: android, gradle, gson, android-gradle-plugin, retrofit

I have included below libraries to my app's lib folder:

1. compile files('libs/retrofit-2.0.0-beta2.jar')
2. compile files('libs/converter-gson-2.0.0-beta1.jar')

When going to run app it gives me such an error:

> Error:(17, 17) error: cannot access HttpUrl class file for
>   com.squareup.okhttp.HttpUrl not found

I have created app including retrofit as said here:
[The biggest update yet on the best HTTP Client Library for Android](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en)

1. As there said: But in Retrofit 2.0, OkHttp is now required and is automatically set as a dependency.

   -- So, did not add OkHttp to my project
2. As there said: But in Retrofit 2.0, Converter is not included in the package anymore. You need to plug a Converter in yourself or Retrofit will be able to accept only the String result. As a result, Retrofit 2.0 doesn't depend on Gson anymore.

   -- So, i decided include **Gson: com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson** to my app, not **'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'**

Any advises how to use retrofit will be helpful. And please advice me how to correct this main Error?

**Solved:**
I searched and find this solution. If you are using proxy to connect internet then simply add it to gradle.properties file:

systemProp.http.proxyHost=xxx
systemProp.http.proxyPort=xxx
systemProp.http.proxyUser=xxx
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=xxx
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost

systemProp.https.proxyHost=xxx
systemProp.https.proxyPort=xxx
systemProp.https.proxyUser=xxx
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=xxx
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost

Thanks to @ilya. It was just network issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jars doesn't contain any information about its dependencies
So when you are adding jars you also have to download and add OkHttp/Gson jars.

```
compile files('libs/okhttp.jar')
compile files('libs/gson.jar')
```

But if you add your dependency in this way

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1'
```

All other required libraries will be downloaded and added by gradle automatically.

The final gradle.build should contain these 2 lines:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta1'
```

Comment: Of course, but i tried to add this libs to my project because i have problem with gradle. And i have posted another question about this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32879768/androidstudio-gradle-sync-not-correctly-works
If you can help me it will be grate to use gradle )

Comment: About your link - I think you have connectivity problems with jcenter.

Comment: yes only connectivity problems can cause it. But what i can do? I opened Settings->Appearance$Behavior->HTTP Proxy . And checked Auto-detect proxy settings. And bottom of this window there Check connection button. And i inserted https://jcenter.bintray.com/ link and clicked to test and it successfull executed. Maybe in another place i must set proxy settings?

Comment: i have added system properties for proxy on gradle.properties file. and it syched. But now it gives me : GsonConverterFactory cannot be converted to Factory by method invocation conversion

Comment: It is more related to retrofit itself. I think it is better to post another question with your code. I can not recommend anything without looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my eclipse project. If you want to use libraries, put these jar´s in your libs folder:

- converter-gson-2.0.0-beta2.jar
- gson-2.3.1.jar
- okhttp-2.7.5.jar
- okio-1.8.0.jar
- retrofit-2.0.0-beta2.jar

After that I was able to use retrofit with the gson converter.

Hope that helps